# Spring WebFlux: Refactoring blocking API with Reactive API, or should I?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a legacy Spring Boot REST app that interacts with downstream services that block. I'm new to reactive programming, and am unsure how to handle these blocking requests. Most Webflux examples I've seen are pretty trivial. Here's the flow-of-control of my app:

1. User queries MyApp at http://myapp.com
2. MyApp then queries partner REST API, which is BLOCKING.
3. Depending on account type, data from the blocking app needs to be queried to make another call to another blocking REST application.
4. All data is enriched and rendered by MyApp to the browser.

Where to start? I'm using WebClient currently, so that part's done. I know I should perform the blocking steps on a different scheduler (parallel or boundedElastic?) Should I use a Flux or Mono, since the partner APIs return the data all at once?

Both apps return thousands of rows of data, and the user just waits... Steps 1-2 take about 4 secs; add in step 3, and we're looking at over 30 seconds due to the inefficiency of the API. Can Flux help my users' wait time at all?

EDIT Below is a (long) example of what my application is doing. Notice that I block my first call to the API to get a count of what's being returned, then I fetch the rest in batches of `TASK_QUERY_LIMIT`.

```
@Bean
public WebClient authWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    final int size = 48 * 1024 * 1024;
    final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
            .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size))
            .build();

    return builder.baseUrl(configProperties.getUrl())
            .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
            .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(map))
            .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
                exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponseStatus());
                exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
            })
            .build();
}

public Mono<Task> getTasksMono() {
    return getAuthWebClient()
            .baseUrl("http://MyApp.com")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, this::onHttpStatusError)
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<Task>>() {}));
}
            
// Service method
public List<Task> getTasksMono() {
    Mono<Response<Task>> monoTasks = getTasksMono();
    Task tasks = monoTasks.block();
    int taskCount = tasks.getCount();
    List<Task> returnTasks = new ArrayList<>(tasks.getData());

    List<Mono<<Task>> tasksMonoList = new ArrayList<>();
    // query API-ONE for all remaining tasks
    if (taskCount > TASK_QUERY_LIMIT) {
        retrieveAdditionalTasks(key, taskCount, tasksMonoList);
    }

    // Send out all of the calls at once, and subscribe to their results.
    Flux.mergeSequential(tasksMonoList)
            .map(Response::getData)
            .doOnNext(returnTasks::addAll)
            .blockLast();

    return returnTasks.stream()
            .map(this::transform) // This method performs business logic on the data before returning to user
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
}

private void retrieveAdditionalTasks(String key, int taskCount,
                                     List<Mono<Response<Task>>> tasksMonoList) {

    int offset = TASK_QUERY_LIMIT;
    int numRequests = (taskCount - offset) / TASK_QUERY_LIMIT + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numRequests; i++) {
        tasksMonoList.add(getTasksMono(processDefinitionKey, encryptedIacToken,
                TASK_QUERY_LIMIT, offset));
        offset += TASK_QUERY_LIMIT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to start? By start coding, you havn’t provided a single line of code. Use google and read the webflux documentation from spring. Also read the reactor documentation from spring. They are far from trivial but will explain what to do. For instance read the scheduler chapter in the reactor docs and it will answer your question

Comment: I will edit my answer with what I have so far, thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what the blocking API is. By using the WebClient all calls are performed  in reactive manner without blocking.

Comment: No, I block the response from WebClient. So it’s not reactive.

Comment: it would be great if you share some code to get more understanding because it's not really clear what do you mean by "partner REST API, which is BLOCKING". REST API itself could not be blocking and you could build very efficient service even if it takes 30 sec to get response. If you just want to take a first step to reactive by switching to WebClient, I would create all request/response logic using reactive API and then block (if required) at the very top level (e.g. in controller).

Comment: As for `Flux` vs `Mono` - it really depends on downstream logic. If you process record-by-record - use `Flux<T>` but if you process data in batches - use `Mono<List<T>>`

Comment: Ok, I will share what I can. But what you described is exactly what I’m doing now. The problem is the APIs I call take 4 - 30 seconds (!) to respond.

Comment: Is the service method an API endpoint on your webapp? If so it should also be a Mono or a Flux, you've gotta use the reactive components all the way through

Comment: Please review code and correct at least obvious issues - missing return statements, not matching return types for some methods, …. Try to create minimal reproducible example. Also, how do you consume this logic? Do you have any REST controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple questions here. Will try to highlight main points

**1. Does it make sense refactoring to Reactive API?**

From the first look your application is IO bound and typically reactive applications are much more efficient because all IO operations are async and non-blocking. Reactive application will not be faster but you will need less resources to  The only caveat is that in order to get all benefits from the reactive API, your app should be reactive end-to-end (reactive drivers for DB, reactive WebClient, …). All reactive logic is executed on `Schedulers.parallel()` and you need small number of threads (by default, number of CPU cores) to execute non-blocking logic. It’s still possible use blocking API by “offloading” them to `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` but it should be an exception (not the rule) to make your app efficient. For more details, check [Flight of the Flux 3 - Hopping Threads and Schedulers](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers).

**2. Blocking vs non-blocking.**

It looks like there is some misunderstanding of the blocking API. It’s not about response time but about underlining API. By default, Spring WebFlux uses Reactor Netty as underlying Http Client library which itself is a reactive implementation of Netty client that uses Event Loop instead of Thread Per Request model. Even if request takes 30-60 sec to get response, thread will not be blocked because all IO operations are async. For such API reactive applications will behave much better because for non-reactive (thread per request) you would need large number of threads and as result much more memory to handle the same workload.

To quantify efficiency we could apply [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) to calculate required number of threads in a ”traditional” thread per request model

`workers >= throughput x latency`, where `workers` - number of threads

For example, to handle 100 QPS with 30 sec latency we would need 100 x 30 = 3000 threads. In reactive app the same workload could be handled by several threads only and, as result, much less memory. For scalability it means that for IO bound reactive apps you would typically scale by CPU usage and for “traditional” most probably by memory.

Sometimes it's not obvious what code is blocking. One very useful tool while testing reactive code is [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) that you could integrate into unit tests.

**3. How to refactor?**

I would migrate layer by layer but block only once. Moving remote calls to WebClient could be a first step to refactor app to reactive API. I would create all request/response logic using reactive API and then block (if required) at the very top level (e.g. in controller). Do’s and Don’ts: [Avoiding First-Time Reactive Programmer Mines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rnMIueRKNU) is a great overview of the common pitfalls and possible migration strategy.

**4. Flux vs Mono.**

`Flux` will not help you to improve performance. It’s more about downstream logic. If you process record-by-record - use `Flux<T>` but if you process data in batches - use `Mono<List<T>>`.

Your current code is not really reactive and very hard to understand mixing reactive API, stream API and blocking multiple times. As a first step try to rewrite it as a single flow using reactive API and block only once.

Not really sure about your internal types but here is some skeleton that could give you an idea about the flow.

```
// Service method
public Flux<Task> getTasks() {
    return getTasksMono()
            .flatMapMany(response -> {
                List<Mono<Response<Task>>> taskRequests = new ArrayList<>();
                taskRequests.add(Mono.just(response));

                if (response.getCount() > TASK_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    retrieveAdditionalTasks(key, response.getCount(), taskRequests);
                }

                return Flux.mergeSequential(taskRequests);
            })
            .flatMapIterable(Response::getData)
            .map(this::transform); // use flatMap in case transform is async
}
```

As I mentioned before, try to keep internal API reactive returning `Mono` or `Flux` and block only once in the upper layer.

Comment: I appreciate this in-depth explanation.

Comment: @CNDyson added code snippet to give you some ideas

Comment: The code snippet REALLY helps!! I've got it now, thanks so much!!

Comment: If I could ask one last question - I'm trying to get a count of all `taskRequests`. When I invoke the `.count()` method, something still hasn't been resolved, because I get `"scanAvailable": true`. Any ideas why?

Comment: The code never executes in the `.flatMapMany()` operation. Is the browser not subscribing to the right object maybe?

Comment: How do you call this API? Please share your controller

Comment: The error was in the return value. I nested the Mono in the POJO, instead of vice-versa. I'm all good now - many thanks again!!