# New to Flux: How to use the value of a Mono in subsequent calls?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

My Spring WebFlux app (trying to refactor from REST) has to query a REST API, and because the result set is so large, I do it in batches. But I need to know the `taskCount` of the total result set to know how many queries to make. So right now I do this, but how do I make it reactive?

In fact, this whole flow needs another set of eyes, because I'm new to Flux and don't think I implemented this quite right. I need to return a `Flux` or `Mono` of `List<TaskResponse>`, which is transformed from `Response<Task>`.

```
public Mono<List<TaskResponse>> getByProcessDefinitionKeyFlux(String processDefinitionKey, String token) {

    Integer taskCount = getTasksMono(processDefinitionKey, token, 1, 0)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("getTasksMono"))
            .map(Response::getCount)
            .block();

    List<Mono<Response<Task>>> tasksMonoList =
            retrieveAdditionalTasks(processDefinitionKey, token, taskCount);

    // Send out all of the calls at once, and subscribe to their results.
    return Flux.mergeSequential(tasksMonoList)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .map(Response::getData)
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
            .map(this::transform)
            .collectList()
            .log();
}

private List<Mono<Response<Task>>> retrieveAdditionalTasks(String processDefinitionKey, String token, int taskCount) {
    int offset = 0;
    int numRequests = (taskCount - offset) / TASK_QUERY_LIMIT + 1;
    List<Mono<Response<Task>>> tasksMonoList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numRequests; i++) {
        tasksMonoList.add(getTasksMono(processDefinitionKey, token,
                TASK_QUERY_LIMIT, offset));
        offset += TASK_QUERY_LIMIT;
    }

    return tasksMonoList;
}

private Mono<Response<Task>> getTasksMono(String processDefinitionKey, String token,
                                                               int limit, int offset) {

    return Objects.requireNonNull(getAuthClient(token)
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> {
                uriBuilder
                        .path("/user-task-instances")
                        .queryParam("sortBy", "createdAt")
                        .queryParam("sortOrder", "ASC")
                        .queryParam("resourceIdType", "")
                        .queryParam("key", key)
                        .queryParam("latest", true)
                        .queryParam("limit", limit)
                        .queryParam("offset", offset)
                        .queryParam("operatingState", "INPROGRESS");
                return uriBuilder.build();
            })
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, this::onHttpStatusError)
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<Task>>() {}));
}
```

Comment: Dont ever call block in a non-blocking application, as it will reduce your application performance by a lot. Also remove all schedulers as you most likely dont need them unless you are calling something blocking like read from the file system or using a blocking database driver.

Comment: I am calling a blocking API that's not mine.

Comment: What blocking api? And you should still NEVER call block in a non-blocking application. If its a rest api then you dont have to block if you are using WebClient. Reactor works with the event loop and if you call block you may loose up to 25% or even more in performance depending on how many cores you have desicared to the service. The reactor documentation clearly explains how to handle blocking calls by yes placing them on their on scheduler, (usually elastic) but you should not block you should instead remove that snd use flatMap and chain on.

Comment: Got it. The block() call is there as we migrate to being fully Flux (this app was originally written in REST). I'd like to remove the blocking, but how can I get the count and page my requests? The API I'm calling in `getTasksMono` is the blocking one.

Comment: Dont just say `its a blocking one` what is the api?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what is it?? it's an internal API that I call. I'll edit my question with the relevant code.

Comment: If you are using `WebClient` which is a NON-BLOCKING httpclient your call is not ”blocking”. If the service you are calling is slow to respond and since spring `WebClient` is NON-BLOCKING spring can switch to doing other stuff while it is waiting. I think you dont really understand what blocking means. Or what a blocking api is. A regular rest service is not blocking. If you would use `RestTemplate` to call another service then you would be blocking because it is inherently blocking. Please read the reactor documentation introduction

Comment: As I stated, I call the BLOCK method of WebClient to get my intermediate result. I KNOW that’s wrong and that’s what I’m trying NOT to do.

Comment: And i wrote in my first comment use `flatMap`

Comment: Example please? In an answer?

Comment: Im on mobile so no, no example. Read what i wrote, remove the schedulers and switch out block for flatMap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring WebFlux: Refactoring blocking API with Reactive API, or should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914528/spring-webflux-refactoring-blocking-api-with-reactive-api-or-should-i)

Comment: @CNDyson Not sure why you asked the same question again but I added some snippet to your previous question. Let's continue there.